# Array nested aggregation with multiple properties

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently we decided to use Elastic Search to speed up most of our queries, based on purchases/sales documents.
At the moment we have an object with a nested array, like so:

```
"customFields": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "key": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "delimiter": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_options": "freqs",
                    "analyzer": "iq_text_delimiter"
                },
                "enum": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 2048
                },
                "joined": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_options": "freqs",
                    "analyzer": "i_text_bigram",
                    "search_analyzer": "q_text_bigram"
                },
                "prefix": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "i_prefix",
                    "search_analyzer": "q_prefix"
                },
                "stem": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "iq_text_stem"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": "iq_text_base"
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "delimiter": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_options": "freqs",
                    "analyzer": "iq_text_delimiter"
                },
                "enum": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 2048
                },
                "joined": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_options": "freqs",
                    "analyzer": "i_text_bigram",
                    "search_analyzer": "q_text_bigram"
                },
                "prefix": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_options": "docs",
                    "analyzer": "i_prefix",
                    "search_analyzer": "q_prefix"
                },
                "stem": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "iq_text_stem"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": "iq_text_base"
        },
        "valueBool": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "valueDate": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "valueNumber": {
            "type": "float"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need, basically, a tree with document count for all the combinations of values in this array.
For example:

`some text|true|2023-11-21|100 = 3;`
`some text|false|2023-11-21|100 = 10;`
`other text|true|2023-01-14|1500 = 2;`
`...`

There is no hierarchy, so the items are not connected in any way, but we have, in a configuration, the levels for the keys, that in one document can be `valueBool > valueNumber > valueDate` and on other `valueNumber > valueDate > value` (all of them are optional, some can be filled, others, not).

I tried several methods that I've found, but none of them seem to work.

I tried using `composite` with the multiple fields, `multi_terms`, `filters`, nested aggregations, `reverse_nested`, you name it! Maybe I'm doing something wrong or not fully understanding how to perform such an aggregation (if it's even possible!).

Any ideas?

P.S: If necessary, I can change the format of the array, the types, etc.